# android vitamio multiple videoview error

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, vitamio

I edit VideoViewDemo because I need two (or more) stream rtsp in same layout.

I use a relative layout with two VideoView and add code in VideoViewDemo to fill each surface.

Result is that two video is overlapping each other and logcat give me many times this error :

```
E/SurfaceTextureClient(4717): Surface::lock failed, already locked
01-15 17:41:07.328: E/VitamioPlayer: LOCK BUFFER FAILED
E/SurfaceTexture(144): [SurfaceView] dequeueBuffer: can’t dequeue multiple buffers without setting the buffer count
```

I make same thing with MediaPlayer demo, with same effect...

I read that this is library bug, someone has solved this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vitamio dont support multiple videoView. maybe will add  in the future.

Comment: Is this still applicable as of Vitamio 5.0.2 release?