# How to play multiple(max four in my case) .m3u8 video streaming in single activity in android?

Tags: android, http-live-streaming, m3u8, exoplayer, vitamio

I've been facing these issues since very long, and I'm really disapointed with android support of HLS as it behaves too randomly.

**Requirement :**

1) Play multiple .m3u8 video streaming

2) Should work on different devices and api levels.

**What I've treid and respective issues :**

**Method - 1)** [TextureView with native MediaPlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview) :

- Number of videos that play depends on device, for some device it's
  playing only one video(My Device - samsung galaxy grand quattro - api
  level 16) and for some devices it's able to play all four video
  streamings.
- Depends on api level, some .m3u8 url are working on jellybean but not
  above kitkat.

**Method - 2)** [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) :

- Same issues of Method -1

**Method - 3)** [Vitamio](https://www.vitamio.org/en/) :

- Successfully play every .m3u8 url
- [No suuport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165283/android-vitamio-multiple-videoview-error) for multiple videoview

**Method - 4)** [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika/) :

- It's not stable, yet(as they've mention).

**Solutions I'm seeking for :**

1) Multiple video streaming should play, as with any above method my device is able to play single video, but it seems [Milestone Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.milestonesys.mobile&hl=en) is able to play 8 video streamings in my device(How? :O).

2) If native MediaPlayer is not able to play some .m3u8 url, then how to debug what is exact issue like is there any problem with aac codec, decoder, segments, .ts file etc. ?

3) If native MediaPlayer is not able to play streaming then, How should I make custom MediaPlayer which supports most streaming urls?

4) Is there any possibility of playing multiple videos with Vitamio?

5) Reference of any other HLS client which meets with my requirement?

Personally I would like to go with Method-1, so is there anything I can do?

Comment: FWIW, different devices will have different limits on how many hardware codecs can be used simultaneously (usually based on some hard resource limit). Many devices will fall back on software implementations, but you will quickly run out of CPU. If you're running up against hardware limitations, there's not much you can do.

Comment: Hey thanks for response, what you've  mention seems right. But Milestone mobile app is able to play 8 videos in single screen.

Comment: @Chitrang: Actually, the Milestone Mobile app displays MJPEG streams, which may or may not pose different constraints on the hardware (or software). I could imagine every still/frame just ends up being decoded into a plain bitmap which then gets rendered on-screen one after another. For actual video streams, fadden's remark holds true, as you may have already discovered from [this related thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9834882/1029225).

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: cause i am able t play m3u8 format in videoview in all versions go through this known issues list https://www.overdigital.com/2013/07/12/how-bad-is-really-hls-on-android/